# Assign value to a NodeJS variable with respect to MongoDB document array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a MongoDB collection with the following documents

```
> db.mycol.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ec6506171ae442136aa97d2"), "uname" : "mail1", "port" : 1000, "abc" : "test1" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ec659e6c0b1cc11370d8378"), "uname" : "mail2", "port" : 1001, "abc" : "test2" }
```

In the below code I am trying to fetch an array of document field `port` by making use of `distinct` in NodeJS.

```
var nextPort=0;
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("mydb");
    dbo.collection("mycol").distinct('port', function(err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(result);
      db.close();
    });
  });
```

The above code gives an output  `[ 1000, 1001 ]` 
Now, I have a variable called `nextPort` I want it to have the next value of already existing ports (should be unique and unused) i.e. if the last element of the array is `1001` then `nextPort=1002`.

How do I assign the next value (unique) from the array elements to my variable. Also is there a way to have all unique values in the document field `port` like we have `primary key` in `MySQL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this will help but you can try assigning the output to a variable, say "array".  Then use nextPort = array[array.length-1]+1
See code sample below:

```
let nextPort=0; 
let arr = [1000, 1001];
nextPort = arr[arr.length-1]+1
```

or if you want to make nextPort an array:

```
let nextPort=[]; 
let arr = [1000, 1001];
nextPort.push(...arr, arr[arr.length-1]+1);
```

The code above assumes your Mongo code will always return a number.

Comment: I need your help with another thing. So basically I have a synchronous function (a child process)  which makes use of nextPort and since it is a synchronous method it takes precedence over the function where I define the value of nextPort. Need a work around with that. As in the cp the nextPort value is set to 0. I have updated the code. Please have a look at it

Comment: So what i want is - make the entire function synchronous MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db)

Comment: mmm.  Forgive my ignorance, but why would you want to make it synchronous as opposed to asynchronous?  Is your goal to create / start multiple containers in parallel?

Comment: Yes, I plan on creating multiple containers. And the MongoDB instance which I plan on provisioning takes port number as nextPort's value. As the child process in a sych function it takes precedence over the fucntion above (nextPort=0). This is the only reason I want the above function to take priority over execSync.

Comment: I have no idea.   But I am fairly certain mongoconnect is asynchronous, which may actually be a good thing, it can ensure you never overwrite a port number or anything worse.     Hope you come right.  There are some super clever people here who I am sure can answer without much effort